# What JQuery plugin uses arrows and lines for site tours?

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I am looking for the name or link to a jquery plugin that lets you set up an interface tour of your website using arrows and text. I have seen this plugin before, but I can no longer find it.*

This is the style of the website tour that I am talking about. Very simple text and arrows -- nothing more. It's not a screenshot of the actual plugin, but one that I found on another SO post that is closest to what I am talking about.

**Does anyone know the name of the plugin I seek?**

[image]

The closest plugin I could find that is similar to this style is the [Chardin.j](http://heelhook.github.io/chardin.js/)s

*Chase.com recently used the arrow/captions style in their redesign of their website to help current customers adapt to the new look. I tried to look at the source code but couldn't figure it out.*